# Добавление в связующую таблицу

Tags: python, django

Добрый день!

Делаю добавление в БД MySQL. При добавлении в таблицу с данными проблем нет, а вот с добавлением связи возникла проблема. То есть мне нужно добавить id только что созданной строки и id пользователя создавшего ее.

Хотел сделать импорт модели, но такой модели не существует. Так что такой вариант отпал. А как еще такое делается я пока что не знаю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Функция [`LAST_INSERT_ID();`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) из `MySQL` возвращает ID последней добавленной записи. Получайте это значение и делайте `INSERT` в вашу связующую таблицу

**UPDATE**

В общем мне стало интересно и я решил попробовать сделать небольшой пример.
Создал две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id integer NOT NULL, -- PrimaryKey
  name character varying(256) NOT NULL,
);
CREATE TABLE table2
(
  id integer NOT NULL, -- PrimaryKey
  name character varying(256) NOT NULL,
)
```

И таблицу связок:

```
CREATE TABLE table1table2
(
  table1_ref integer NOT NULL,
  table2_ref integer NOT NULL,
  id integer NOT NULL, -- PrimaryKey
)
```

Связал их внешними ключами и указал первичные. Получили вот такие модельки:

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table1'

class Table1Table2(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    table1_ref = models.ForeignKey(Table1, db_column='table1_ref')
    table2_ref = models.ForeignKey('Table2', db_column='table2_ref')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table1table2'

class Table2(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table2'
```

Далее пишем скрипт, который успешно отрабатывает и создает нужные нам записи:

```
from models import Table1, Table2, Table1Table2

t1 = Table1(id=1, name='record #1 in table1')
t1.save()

t2 = Table2(id=1, name='record #1 in table2')
t2.save()

t1t2 = Table1Table2(id=1, table1_ref=t1, table2_ref=t2)
t1t2.save()
```

Самое интересное, что если у таблицы `tabel1table2` не будет первичного ключа то на строчке `t1t2.save()` получим ошибку, суть которой сводится к тому, что у таблицы нет этого самого первичного ключа. При этом в `tabel1table2` он нам как бы вообще не нужен, но пришлось создать чтобы `django` все-таки сделал то, что нам надо (причем составной из `table1_ref` и `table2_ref` не проканал).

Из вышеизложенного следует вопрос к более опытным товарищам: а можно ли такое провернуть без первичного ключа в `table1table2`?

Comment: Если бы я работал напрямую с MySQL то проблем бы у меня не возникло, а у меня проблема в том, что я не знаю как это сделать через Django ORM

Comment: Тогда посмотрите [это][1]


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#auto-incrementing-primary-keys

Comment: Проблема не в том что узнать id, а в том как его записать в таблицу, которую Django создал(а/о) автоматически для связи ManyToMany.

Comment: Тогда прошу прощения за ответы не по теме:)

Comment: Обновил ответ